# Difference between objectAtIndexedSubscript and objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have searched quite bit on stackoverflow and other resources, can't find an answer.

What is the difference between the NSArray methods `objectAtIndexedSubscript` and `objectAtIndex`?

Or, if there is no difference, why do both exist?

In the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndexedSubscript:) it says they are "identical".

I am super new to programming but if they are identical, isn't that breaking the DRY principle? Obviously the guys at Apple know what they are doing, but why are they both provided if they are identical? Or maybe a better question is, why should I use one over the other?

Comment: Interesting question, before you ask this question, I did not even know the existence of `objectAtIndexedSubscript`!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They are identical.

`-objectAtIndex:` is the method you should use.

`-objectAtIndexedSubscript:` is the method that provides support for obj-c subscripts. In other words, this method is what the compiler uses if you say `array[3]`. But for `NSArray*` it does the exact same thing as `-objectAtIndex:`. The reason why it's a different method is so other classes can implement this in order to support obj-c subscripts without having to use the generically-named `-objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: Thanks @kevin-ballard.  I found more info about [obj-c subscripts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) here, thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: @kevin-ballard So is it to make available “different behaviour” when you do “array[3]” and [array objectAtIndex:3]  ? (Where array is the child class of NSArray which implemented “objectAtIndexSubscript" DIFFERENTLY from  “objectAtIndex" method ?

Comment: @bluesm: It's because the compiler didn't want to make any assumptions about the method `-objectAtIndex:`, as it was a preexisting method. Instead it wanted to define a new method that classes could choose to implement if they wanted `foo[3]` behavior. It just happens that with `NSArray*`, `-objectAtIndex:` already has correct behavior, so the two methods behave the same. Note that there's also `-objectForKeyedSubscript:`, to allow indexing like `foo[@"bar"]`, which `NSDictionary*` uses.

Comment: @KevinBallard So foo[3] basically links to the "objectAtIndexedSubscript:" message,  and foo[@"bar"] to the "objectForKeyedSubscript:" message. That's it, whether object implement those methods (and by implementing this syntax work), is up to programmer. Right ?

Comment: @bluesm: Yes. These methods exist so your custom container class can benefit from `foo[3]` and `foo[@"bar"]` syntax. Merely implementing `-objectAtIndexedSubscript:` allows `foo[3]` to work, and `-objectForKeyedSubscript:` allows `foo[@"bar"]` to work.